# Buscar datos en JTable

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton

**Buenas, tengo problemas con el siguiente código, espero alguien me pueda ayudar o asesorar**

Antes que nada aclaro que soy nuevo en el tema, la ayuda la solicito para un proyecto de la carrera.

Requiero que el botón buscar pueda traer los datos que se esperan del JTable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
        package dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv;
    import Metodos.ConexionBD;
    import static java.awt.image.ImageObserver.WIDTH;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author IDEX2164
 */
public class RHBaja extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  ConexionBD con = new ConexionBD();
  Connection cn = con.Connection();

    
    public RHBaja() {
        initComponents();
        MostrarDatos();        
        
    }
    
        public void MostrarDatos (){
        
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        modelo.addColumn("NumEmpleado");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellidos");
        modelo.addColumn("Fecha de nacimiento");
        modelo.addColumn("CURP");
        modelo.addColumn("RFC");
        modelo.addColumn("Sueldo");
        modelo.addColumn("Puesto");
        modelo.addColumn("Sucursal");
        modelo.addColumn("Fecha de ingreso");
        
        JTDatos.setModel(modelo);
        
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE NumEmpleado LIKE '%"+txtBuscar+"' ORDER BY NumEmpleado";
                
        String datos []= new String [10];
      try {
          Statement st = cn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
          while (rs.next()){
              datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
              datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
              datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
              datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
              datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
              datos[5] = rs.getString(6);
              datos[6] = rs.getString(7);
              datos[7] = rs.getString(8);
              datos[8] = rs.getString(9);
              datos[9] = rs.getString(10);
              modelo.addRow(datos);
          }
                    
          JTDatos.setModel(modelo);
                    
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
      }
                       
}
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLnumempleado = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtBuscar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnBuscarEmpleado = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SalirHRBaja = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        JTDatos = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/menos.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Baja de personal");

        JLnumempleado.setText("Numero de empleado");

        txtBuscar.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtBuscarKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        btnBuscarEmpleado.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/buscar.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnBuscarEmpleado.setText("Buscar");
        btnBuscarEmpleado.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnBuscarEmpleadoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/archivo-bin.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Eliminar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        SalirHRBaja.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/cerrar-sesion.png"))); // NOI18N
        SalirHRBaja.setText("Salir");
        SalirHRBaja.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SalirHRBajaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JTDatos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {}
            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(JTDatos);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 634, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(SalirHRBaja))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                                    .addComponent(JLnumempleado)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(txtBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(btnBuscarEmpleado))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addContainerGap()
                                    .addComponent(jButton2))))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(JLnumempleado)
                    .addComponent(txtBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnBuscarEmpleado))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(SalirHRBaja)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void SalirHRBajaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        int Salir = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea salir del programa?");
        if (Salir == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        System.exit(WIDTH);
        }
        if (Salir == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        }
        if (Salir == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelado");
        }
    }                                           

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int Eliminar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea eliminar el registro?");
        if (Eliminar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se elimino el registro");
        }
        if (Eliminar == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se elimino registro");
        }
        if (Eliminar == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelado");
        }
    }                                        

    private void btnBuscarEmpleadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
          
        String buscar = txtBuscar.getText();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se realizo busqueda");
    }                                                 

    private void txtBuscarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      

    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RHBaja().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel JLnumempleado;
    private javax.swing.JTable JTDatos;
    private javax.swing.JButton SalirHRBaja;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnBuscarEmpleado;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

El Código que conecta a la BD es el siguiente:

```
package Metodos;

import dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv.RHBaja;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author mizzo
 */
public class ConexionBD {

    public static RHBaja buscar_reg(String NumeroEmpleado) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    Connection cn;
int variable=0;
    Statement st; 
    
    
    //Se declara la conexión
    public Connection Connection(){
try{
    //Se manda llamar la base de datos con la cual se va a trabajar
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","user","12345");
System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
variable+=1;
} 
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
{
    //Muestra un diálogo de error para avisar que algo está mal
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de revisar Xampp", "Error de Conexión", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
     
   //Para el programador se agrega el mensaje de salida por consola, para trabajar el error
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}return cn;
    }
Statement createStatement(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No soportado");    
}
    PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    PreparedStatement createStatement(String sql) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
}
```

Los datos se almacenan correctamente en la base de datos, en el JTable solo realizo un select a la tabla personal, pero quiero agregar la función de buscar por numero de empleado.

Disculpen si no soy muy especifico, es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para buscar en un JTable yo lo que hago es:

- Ingresar un dato para buscar.
- Dar a un botón que me lleve a un método que busque en la BBDD.
- LIMPIO TODA LA JTABLE (elimino todos los datos).
- Relleno otra vez el jtable con los datos que me devuelve la consulta de la búsqueda.

Con esta lógica lo que hace es que cada vez que buscas algo, solo te muestra ese dato en la JTABLE, eliminado todos. Si le das a buscar (sin poner algo en la búsqueda), se muestran todos otra vez.

[image: Tabla original con dos datos introducidos]

Los datos me los he inventado, pero para el ejemplo te sirve.

[image: Tabla con la búsqueda del usuario 2]

Te pongo el código de la aplicación:

Conexión a la BBDD

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author mizzo
     */
    public class ConexionBD {
    
        public static RHBaja buscar_reg(String NumeroEmpleado) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose
                                                                            // Tools | Templates.
        }
    
        
        Connection cn;
        int variable = 0;
        Statement st;
    
        // Se declara la conexión
        public Connection Connection() {
            try {
                // Se manda llamar la base de datos con la cual se va a trabajar
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false",
                        "user", "12345");
                System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
                variable += 1;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // Muestra un diálogo de error para avisar que algo está mal
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de revisar Xampp", "Error de Conexión",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    
                // Para el programador se agrega el mensaje de salida por consola, para trabajar
                // el error
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return cn;
        }
    
        Statement createStatement() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No soportado");
        }
    
        PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose
                                                                            // Tools | Templates.
        }
    
        PreparedStatement createStatement(String sql) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose
                                                                            // Tools | Templates.
        }
    
    }
```

Código de la aplicación:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author IDEX2164
 */
public class RHBaja extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ConexionBD con = new ConexionBD();
    Connection cn = con.Connection();
    private DefaultTableModel modelo; // nuevo

    public RHBaja() {
        initComponents();
        MostrarDatos();
        rellenarDatos();

    }

    private void rellenarDatos() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM personal ORDER BY NumEmpleado";

        String datos[] = new String[10];
        try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
                datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
                datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
                datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
                datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
                datos[5] = rs.getString(6);
                datos[6] = rs.getString(7);
                datos[7] = rs.getString(8);
                datos[8] = rs.getString(9);
                datos[9] = rs.getString(10);
                modelo.addRow(datos);
            }

            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }

    public void MostrarDatos() {

        // DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

        modelo.addColumn("NumEmpleado");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellidos");
        modelo.addColumn("Fecha de nacimiento");
        modelo.addColumn("CURP");
        modelo.addColumn("RFC");
        modelo.addColumn("Sueldo");
        modelo.addColumn("Puesto");
        modelo.addColumn("Sucursal");
        modelo.addColumn("Fecha de ingreso");

        JTDatos.setModel(modelo);

        // String sql = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE NumEmpleado LIKE '%"+txtBuscar+"'
        // ORDER BY NumEmpleado";
        

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLnumempleado = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtBuscar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnBuscarEmpleado = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SalirHRBaja = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        JTDatos = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        // jLabel1.setIcon(new
        // javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/menos.png")));
        // // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Baja de personal");

        JLnumempleado.setText("Numero de empleado");

        txtBuscar.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtBuscarKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        // btnBuscarEmpleado.setIcon(new
        // javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/buscar.png")));
        // // NOI18N
        btnBuscarEmpleado.setText("Buscar");
        btnBuscarEmpleado.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnBuscarEmpleadoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // jButton2.setIcon(new
        // javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/archivo-bin.png")));
        // // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Eliminar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // SalirHRBaja.setIcon(new
        // javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpoo2_u2_a3_mifv/cerrar-sesion.png")));
        // // NOI18N
        SalirHRBaja.setText("Salir");
        SalirHRBaja.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SalirHRBajaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JTDatos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
//                {},
//                {},
//                {},
//                {}
        }, new String[] {

        }));
        
        modelo = (DefaultTableModel) JTDatos.getModel();

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(JTDatos);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                        layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(jScrollPane1,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 634, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGroup(
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout
                                                .createSequentialGroup().addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(SalirHRBaja))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(layout
                                        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(38, 38, 38)
                                                        .addComponent(JLnumempleado).addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                        .addComponent(txtBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(btnBuscarEmpleado))
                                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                                                        .addComponent(jButton2))))
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addContainerGap()));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(JLnumempleado)
                                .addComponent(txtBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(btnBuscarEmpleado))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27).addComponent(SalirHRBaja).addContainerGap()));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void SalirHRBajaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int Salir = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea salir del programa?");
        if (Salir == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(WIDTH);
        }
        if (Salir == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        }
        if (Salir == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelado");
        }
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int Eliminar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea eliminar el registro?");
        if (Eliminar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se elimino el registro");
        }
        if (Eliminar == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se elimino registro");
        }
        if (Eliminar == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelado");
        }
    }

    private void btnBuscarEmpleadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String buscar_id = txtBuscar.getText();
        buscar(buscar_id);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se realizo busqueda");
    }

    /**
     * Buscamos en la tabla de datos por el NumEmpleado
     * @param buscar_id
     */
    private void buscar(String buscar_id) {

        limpiarTabla();
        
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE NumEmpleado LIKE '%" + buscar_id + "' ORDER BY NumEmpleado";

        String datos[] = new String[10];
        try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
                datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
                datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
                datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
                datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
                datos[5] = rs.getString(6);
                datos[6] = rs.getString(7);
                datos[7] = rs.getString(8);
                datos[8] = rs.getString(9);
                datos[9] = rs.getString(10);
                modelo.addRow(datos);
            }

            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Limpiamos la JTable
     */
    private void limpiarTabla() {

        
    
        int filas=JTDatos.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0;filas>i; i++) {
            modelo.removeRow(0);
        }

    }

    private void txtBuscarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code
        // (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default
         * look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RHBaja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // </editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RHBaja().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel JLnumempleado;
    private javax.swing.JTable JTDatos;
    private javax.swing.JButton SalirHRBaja;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnBuscarEmpleado;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscar;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Básicamente hacemos lo que te he comentado, borramos todos los datos que haya en la JTable y volvemos a rellenarla con los datos que nos devuelva la consulta de buscar y si no introducimos ningún dato y damos a buscar, nos aparecerán de nuevo todos los datos.

Te he comentado las líneas de los iconos por no ponerme a buscar iconos...

Este es el enfoque que yo utilizaría y es funcional, no sé exactamente si es lo que buscabas, de todos modos, échale un vistazo al código y espero que te pueda servir.

Saludos.